# Scrolling multiple Tkinter listboxes together

Tags: python, listbox, scrollbar, tkinter, mousewheel

I have multiple Tkinter listboxes that I have scrolling together using a single scrollbar, but I'd ALSO like them to scroll together for mousewheel activity over any of the listboxes.

How to do this?

My current code is based on the last pattern discussed here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm  It works fine when using only the scrollbar, but the listboxes scroll independently when the mousewheel is used.

Comment: I suppose it would also be acceptable to disable the mousewheel over the individual listboxes, if that's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solve the problem pretty much the same way as you did to connect the two widgets to a single scrollbar: create custom bindings for the mousewheel and have those bindings affect both listboxes rather than just one.

The only real trick is knowing that you get different events for the mousewheel depending on the platform: windows and the Mac gets `<MouseWheel>` events, linux gets `<Button-4>` and `<Button-5>` events.

Here's an example, tested on my Mac with python 2.5:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.OnVsb)
        self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(self.root, yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(self.root, yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right",fill="y")
        self.lb1.pack(side="left",fill="x", expand=True)
        self.lb2.pack(side="left",fill="x", expand=True)
        self.lb1.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
        self.lb2.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
        for i in range(100):
            self.lb1.insert("end","item %s" % i)
            self.lb2.insert("end","item %s" % i)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnVsb(self, *args):
        self.lb1.yview(*args)
        self.lb2.yview(*args)

    def OnMouseWheel(self, event):
        self.lb1.yview("scroll", event.delta,"units")
        self.lb2.yview("scroll",event.delta,"units")
        # this prevents default bindings from firing, which
        # would end up scrolling the widget twice
        return "break"

app=App()
```

Comment: Under Ubunto 10.10, I'm still seeing independent mousewheel scrolling when the mouse is over each listbox.

Comment: @BobC: if you used the above code exactly as posted, yes, you will see that. Did you read the part where I say that linux has different events for the mouse wheel? Ubuntu is linux.

Comment: Doh! On Linux, the mousewheel uses events <Button-4> and <Button-5>.  To be general, I'm binding all 3.

Comment: Plus, the Linux event.delta is 120, so the following snippet ensures smooth scrolling:
        if (event.num == 4):
            delta = -1
        elif (event.num == 5):
            delta = 1
        else:
            delta = event.delta

Comment: I was having the same problem. Just noticed a thing. I created a list of listboxes and used a for-loop to bind the same event to every one of them and another for-loop inside OnMouseWheel() to iterate over each listbox. It didn't work  with event.delta, because the listboxes were scrolling in different directions from the one my mouse was over. This can be fixed by just saying -(event.delta). Works on Windows, Python 3.5.1

Comment: This doesn't react to scrolling by keyboard arrows.

Comment: @Danon: yes, of course. It can, by adding the appropriate bindings. This question wasn't about using arrow keys

Answer (score 16):

I know this is pretty old, but I think the solution is a bit more simple than those proferred here. Assuming that you **always** want the listboxes to be in agreement, then the above two answers aren't even complete solutions - changing selection by means of the arrow keys will scroll one listbox but not the other.

So, looking at the answers, I asked - why aren't they hooking the yscrollcommand callback instead of just sending it straight to the scrollbar? So, I did just that:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *


class MultipleScrollingListbox(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Scrolling Multiple Listboxes')

        #the shared scrollbar
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')

        #note that yscrollcommand is set to a custom method for each listbox
        self.list1 = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand=self.yscroll1)
        self.list1.pack(fill='y', side='left')

        self.list2 = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand=self.yscroll2)
        self.list2.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side='left')

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        #fill the listboxes with stuff
        for x in xrange(30):
            self.list1.insert('end', x)
            self.list2.insert('end', x)

    #I'm sure there's probably a slightly cleaner way to do it than this
    #Nevertheless - whenever one listbox updates its vertical position,
    #the method checks to make sure that the other one gets updated as well.
    #Without the check, I *think* it might recurse infinitely.
    #Never tested, though.
    def yscroll1(self, *args):
        if self.list2.yview() != self.list1.yview():
            self.list2.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yscroll2(self, *args):
        if self.list1.yview() != self.list2.yview():
            self.list1.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yview(self, *args):
        self.list1.yview(*args)
        self.list2.yview(*args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MultipleScrollingListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current solution, coded as a stand-alone function (yes, it should be an object).

Features/requirements:

- It handles any number of lists
  (minimum 1).
- All lists must presently have the
  same length.
- The width of each listbox width is
  adjusted to match the content.
- The listboxes scroll together using
  either the mouse wheel or the
  scrollbar.
- Should work on Windows, OSX and
  Linux, but has been tested only on
  Linux.

Code:

```
def showLists(l, *lists):
    """
    Present passed equal-length lists in adjacent scrollboxes.
    """
    # This exists mainly for me to start learning about Tkinter.
    # This widget reqires at least one list be passed, and as many additional
    # lists as desired.  Each list is displayed in its own listbox, with
    # additional listboxes added to the right as needed to display all lists.
    # The width of each listbox is set to match the max width of its contents.
    # Caveat: Too wide or too many lists, and the widget can be wider than the screen!
    # The listboxes scroll together, using either the scrollbar or mousewheel.

    # :TODO: Refactor as an object with methods.
    # :TODO: Move to a separate file when other widgets are built.

    # Check arguments
    if (l is None) or (len(l) < 1):
        return
    listOfLists = [l]     # Form a list of lists for subsequent processing
    listBoxes = []  # List of listboxes
    if len(lists) > 0:
        for list in lists:
            # All lists must match length of first list
            # :TODO: Add tail filling for short lists, with error for long lists
            if len(list) != len(l):
                return
            listOfLists.append(list)

    import Tkinter

    def onVsb(*args):
        """
        When the scrollbar moves, scroll the listboxes.
        """
        for lb in listBoxes:
            lb.yview(*args)

    def onMouseWheel(event):
        """
        Convert mousewheel motion to scrollbar motion.
        """
        if (event.num == 4):    # Linux encodes wheel as 'buttons' 4 and 5
            delta = -1
        elif (event.num == 5):
            delta = 1
        else:                   # Windows & OSX
            delta = event.delta
        for lb in listBoxes:
            lb.yview("scroll", delta, "units")
        # Return 'break' to prevent the default bindings from
        # firing, which would end up scrolling the widget twice.
        return "break"

    # Create root window and scrollbar
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Samples w/ time step < 0')
    vsb = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL, command=onVsb)
    vsb.pack(side=Tkinter.RIGHT, fill=Tkinter.Y)

    # Create listboxes
    for i in xrange(0,len(listOfLists)):
        lb = Tkinter.Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        lb.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)
        # Bind wheel events on both Windows/OSX & Linux;
        lb.bind("<MouseWheel>", onMouseWheel)
        lb.bind("<Button-4>", onMouseWheel)
        lb.bind("<Button-5>", onMouseWheel)
        # Fill the listbox
        maxWidth = 0
        for item in listOfLists[i]:
            s = str(item)
            if len(s) > maxWidth:
                maxWidth = len(s)
            lb.insert(Tkinter.END, s)
        lb.config(width=maxWidth+1)
        listBoxes.append(lb)        # Add listbox to list of listboxes

    # Show the widget
    Tkinter.mainloop()
# End of showLists()
```

Suggestions for improvements are welcome!

Comment: Just noticed I hard-coded root.title: You will probably want something different.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a very simple procedural solution. After looking on the tutorials point site for information on how to use the scrollbar for one widget (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm), I adapted it to scroll through multiple text boxes at the same time (you can change the code so it uses list boxes). This solution will update all three textboxes when you use the scroll bar.

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 200
WIDTH = 300

def scroll(x, y):
    l_textbox.yview(x,y)
    m_textbox.yview(x,y)
    r_textbox.yview(x,y)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH, bg = "white")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg ='white')
frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)

l_label = tk.Label (frame, text = "Left")
l_label.place(relx=0, rely=0)

m_label = tk.Label (frame, text= "Middle")
m_label.place(relx=0.3, rely=0)

r_label = tk.Label (frame, text= "Right")
r_label.place(relx=0.6, rely=0)

l_textbox = tk.Text(frame, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
l_textbox.config(font = ('Arial',9))
l_textbox.place(relx=0, rely=0.2,relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8)

m_textbox = tk.Text(frame, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
m_textbox.config(font = ('Arial',9))
m_textbox.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2,relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8)

r_textbox = tk.Text(frame, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
r_textbox.config(font = ('Arial',9))
r_textbox.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.2,relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.8)

scrollbar.config( command = scroll)
scrollbar.place(relx = 0.9, relwidth = 0.1,relheight = 1)

for i in range(0, 100):
    l_textbox.insert(tk.INSERT, str(i)+"\n")
    m_textbox.insert(tk.INSERT, str(i)+"\n")
    r_textbox.insert(tk.INSERT, str(i)+"\n")
    l_textbox.place()
    m_textbox.place()
    r_textbox.place()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The listing below is a Python implementation of the Tcl code example from the John K. Ousterhout's book `Tcl and Tk Toolkit - 2009`, chapter `18.9.2 Synchronized Scrolling of Multiple Widgets`:

> It is not necessary to connect the scrollbar and widget directly. A procedure
> can be used in between to do things like scrolling multiple widgets with a
> single scrollbar. The trick to getting accurate synchronized scrolling is to
> identify a master widget that will control the scrollbar and the slave
> widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Scrolling multiple listboxes together


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.config(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(command=self.scrollbar_command)
        self.lb1 = tk.Listbox(
            self.root, yscrollcommand=self.lb1_yscrollcommand)
        self.lb2 = tk.Listbox(
            self.root, yscrollcommand=self.lb2_yscrollcommand)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.lb1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.lb2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        # Generate some dummy data
        for i in range(100):
            self.lb1.insert("end", f"item lb1 {i}")
            self.lb2.insert("end", f"item lb2 {i}")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def lb1_yscrollcommand(self, *args):
        """Only one listbox should update the scrollbar.
        Listbox 'lb1' plays the role of the master listbox.
        It controls the scrollbar and the 'slave' listbox 'lb2' """

        print("lb1_yscrollcommand:", args)
        self.vsb.set(*args)  # update the scrollbar
        self.lb2.yview("moveto", args[0])  # update the 'slave' listbox

    def lb2_yscrollcommand(self, *args):
        """Slave listbox 'lb2' controls the master listbox 'lb1' """

        print("lb2_yscrollcommand:", args)
        self.lb1.yview("moveto", args[0])  # update the 'master' listbox

    def scrollbar_command(self, *args):
        """Scrollbar controls listboxes"""
        self.lb1.yview(*args)
        self.lb2.yview(*args)


app = App()
```

Tested on Linux and on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this question a while ago and not understanding the answers, I have now made and understood my own implementation of this problem **with the mouse wheel**, as below:

The bind argument for scrolling is **different between operating systems**. On Windows it is `'<MouseWheel>'`, on Mac it is `<'Button-4'>`, and on Linux it is `<'Button-5'>`. So, first you can find the operating system of the user like this:

```
from sys import platform
global OS
if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'linux2':
    OS = 'Linux'
elif platform == 'darwin':
    OS = 'Mac'
elif platform == 'win32' or platform == 'win64':
    OS = 'Windows'
else:
    raise Exception("An error occurred in determining user's operating system.")
```

**Declaring and binding listbox widgets:**
Tkinter will only allow one listbox to have a selection at any time if the `exportselection = False` argument is not put into the widget declaration. Even if the listboxes can scroll together, there are still ways the user can mess up the scroll synchronization by scrolling through means other than the mouse wheel.

- `<'B1-Leave'>` allows the user to scroll listboxes by clicking the mouse and dragging out of the widget.
- `<'ButtonRelease-1'>` allows the user to change the secondary selection of the listbox by clicking and dragging
- `<'Key'>` allows the user to scroll listboxes with the arrow keys

These events have to be stopped to maintain scroll synchronization, which has to be done by the event hitting a `break` statement. Even if the event is passed to another function, if it doesn't hit a `break`, it will still proceed. To break off an event in a bind statement, **`'break'` must be a string**. For example:

```
LB1 = Listbox(parent, bg = White, height = 20, width = 1, relief = 'sunken', exportselection = False, selectmode = 'single') #Width = 1 note on line 75
LB1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
LB1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: SearchListboxClick(event, listOfListboxes, LB1))
LB1.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: CombinedListboxScroll(event, listOfListboxes))
LB1.bind('<Button-4>', lambda event: CombinedListboxScroll(event, listOfListboxes))
LB1.bind('<Button-5>', lambda event: CombinedListboxScroll(event, listOfListboxes))
LB1.bind('<B1-Leave>', lambda event: 'break') #Stops listbox scrolling by clicking mouse and dragging
LB1.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda event: 'break') #Stops listbox secondary selection being changed by mouse click and drag
LB1.bind('<Key>', lambda event: 'break') #Stops arrow keys from
```

**Repeat this for all listboxes**, and create a list of the listboxes you want to scroll synchronously:

```
listOfListboxes = [LB1, LB2, LB3, LB4, LB5]
```

Then, to scroll your listboxes, you can either do so for whatever operating system you know you will be running on, or accomodating for any operating system, like this (the scroll speeds are different between operating systems, necessitating the different math):

```
def CombinedListboxScroll(event, listOfListboxes):
    '''Takes list of listboxes and scrolls all of them simultaneously.'''
    if OS == 'Windows':
        for lb in listOfListboxes:
            lb.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta/120)), 'units')
    elif OS == 'Mac':
        for lb in listOfListboxes:
            lb.yview_scroll(int(-1 * event.delta), 'units')
    else: #OS == Linux
        for lb in listOfListboxes:
            lb.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta/120)), 'units')
```

Also, to combine the selection of all the listboxes into one row for the user, you could use a function like this:

```
def CombinedListboxSelect(event, listOfListboxes, boxClicked):
    '''Takes a list of listboxes, and sets their selection to an index clicked by the user in boxClicked.'''
    if boxClicked.curselection() != (): #To stop blank tuples erroring the function. I don't know why they are passed sometimes
        selectedIndex = (boxClicked.curselection())[0] #Parenthesis have to be like this
        boxClicked.selection_set(selectedIndex)
        for listbox in listOfListboxes:
            listbox.selection_clear(0, END) #If this is not done, the last selected item will stay selected on top of the new one also being selected.
            listbox.selection_set(selectedIndex)
```