# Python: Listbox without border

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, border

I want to get a table, but when I realized, that there's no table in python, I decided to fix it with two listboxes.

The point is, that I don't want a border between them.

So my Question is: *How to remove the border from the Tk Listbox in Python?*

Even if it'll become white I had a solution...

Comment: Can you show us your code? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by ”there's no table in python,”?

Comment: @leo : It looks like ProgrammingDonkey wants to put an HTML-style table in their tkinter GUI.

Comment: ProgrammingDonkey, [Tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_%28software%29) is just one of several GUI toolkits which can be used in Python. It's not specific to Python, and plenty of us don't even have it installed, and prefer to use more powerful systems like GTK, or Qt, etc in our programs.

Comment: @PM2Ring: why do you think GTK or QT is more powerful? How do you define "power"? Tkinter is more than powerful enough for most tasks. I wouldn't write the next photoshop in it, but for most projects it's quite capable.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, I didn't see the tkinter tag

Comment: @BryanOakley : Sorry if my comment came off like I was putting down tkinter. I was mostly trying to clarify for the OP that tkinter wasn't peculiar to Python, or indeed part of the standard Python package, even if it is often bundled with Python on certain platforms.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sure, tkinter is more than powerful enough for most tasks. And it's probably less intimidating to learn than GTK or Qt; both of those have so much stuff in them that it takes a *long* time to learn it all.

Comment: @BryanOakley FWIW, I've never used Qt, but I've been using GTK for at least 7 years. I had a look at tkinter when I was first learning Python, and it was ok, but the look of the GUIs it made back then were less slick than the equivalent GTK or Qt GUIs. OTOH, it'd be pretty easy for someone who was familiar with tkinter to get into GTK. But I guess this isn't really the appropriate place for an extended discussion on the merits of various GUI systems. :)

Answer (score 7):

You want to set the borderwidth to zero, but you also want to set highlightthickness to zero. Highlightthickness represents a rectangle that surrounds the whole widget when it has keyboard focus. Finally, when you use pack or grid, make sure you don't add any padding between them.

If you want to complete the illusion that the two widgets are one, put them in a frame and give the frame a borderwidth and relief.
import Tkinter as tk

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")

        lb1 = tk.Listbox(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        lb2 = tk.Listbox(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        lb1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        lb2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        lb1.insert(0, "left")
        lb2.insert(0, "right")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=8, pady=8)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can achieve would be this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

wrapper = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief="sunken")
L1 = tk.Listbox(wrapper, bd=0)
L2 = tk.Listbox(wrapper, bd=0)

L1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
L2.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

wrapper.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

note setting the border of each listbox to 0, (bd=0) and to give the overall widget a similar look to the original listbox i've wrapped it in a frame and given that the same border style as the default listbox.

also worth nothing that you need to get the bindings right to make them scroll as expected, just binding to the scroll wheel and scroll bar is insufficient as the lists can be moved with the arrow keys when an item is highlighted, like in the second example on this page:
[scrolling multiple listboxes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066974/scrolling-multiple-tkinter-listboxes-together)
by Santiclause

Comment: no problem, if you're happy with this can you mark it as the answer, and just as an FYI, you can extend that method to do more than 2 listboxes, and if you're going to using it a lot within an application its a good idea to subclass it, as this prevents you having to manually type out how they link up.

Answer (score 1):

Speicfy [`borderwidth`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.config-method) as 0 when you create a listbox.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import *  # from tkinter import *   (Python 3.x)

root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(borderwidth=0)  # <---
lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table in tkinter I recommend using tree view and setting it to “headings” this is equivalent of a table.
https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-treeview/