# Display text on both sides of a scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

I am very new to Tkinter.

I'm trying to build a chat system in which I want to display the user's query on the left of the scrollbar and the response by the system on its right. Is it possible to do it?

Currently, all comes on one side.This is how scrollview looks like

[image]

The code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as ttk 
from ttk import *

master = Tk()

rectangleFrame = Frame(master)
rectangleFrame.grid(column =50, row = 50, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
rectangleFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
rectangleFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
rectangleFrame.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

def getEdittextValue(*args):
    listbox.insert(END, "You: Something")
    listbox.itemconfig(END, {'bg':'red', 'fg':'black'})
    listbox.insert(END, "Bot: something else")
    listbox.itemconfig(END, {'bg':'grey', 'fg':'blue'})


scrollbar = Scrollbar(rectangleFrame, width = 30)
scrollbar.grid(sticky="NWEW")
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)

listbox = Listbox(rectangleFrame)
listbox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)


listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
query_button = Button(rectangleFrame, command=getEdittextValue, text = "Process")
query_button.pack()
rectangleFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

master.mainloop()
```

I am doing 2 inserts in the function. One with user query and another with system's response.

Comment: Please, edit your post to make your code _runnable_ (add imports and the remaining necessary code), so that we can try it on our computers, in order to give you a solution based on your example.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: I know it's offtopic, but what's a point of use such nasty import statements?

Answer (score 1):

If you want query and response separated by the scrollbar, you need to use 2 listboxes. My code to scroll them together is based on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm and if you also want to scroll them together with the mousewheel too, see the answer to this question: [Scrolling multiple Tkinter listboxes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066974/scrolling-multiple-tkinter-listboxes-together).

You have been mixing pack and grid layout (for `rectangleFrame` for instance) which are incompatible. You need to choose one and stick to it. I used pack in my code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

rectangleFrame = ttk.Frame(master)
rectangleFrame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill="both", expand=True)

count = 0  # query counter to see that both listboxes are scrolled together

def getEdittextValue():
    global count
    listbox_query.insert("end", "You: query %i" % count)
    listbox_query.itemconfig("end", {'bg':'red', 'fg':'black'})
    listbox_response.insert("end", "Bot:response %i" % count)
    listbox_response.itemconfig("end", {'bg':'grey', 'fg':'blue'})
    count += 1

def yview(*args):
    """ scroll both listboxes together """
    listbox_query.yview(*args)
    listbox_response.yview(*args)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(rectangleFrame)
listbox_query = tk.Listbox(rectangleFrame)
listbox_response = tk.Listbox(rectangleFrame)

scrollbar.config(command=yview)
listbox_query.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox_response.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

query_button = ttk.Button(rectangleFrame, command=getEdittextValue, text="Process")

listbox_query.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
listbox_response.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
query_button.pack(side="left")

master.mainloop()
```